# How can I use a captcha in a form that is not an add-on?

Tags: forms, extension, captcha

I'm using a form in a web page that is standard html and css, NOT any kind of Exp Eng add-on tag set. Is there a way to use Exp Eng's captcha system directly in a webpage form like a typical Exp Eng tag? I've been using reCAPTCHA from Brandon Jones and like it a lot but it is an extension that automatically replaces the Exp Eng captcha. Can a simple add-on be written that uses the extension and embeds a captcha in the page?

Comment: I don't think, it would be possible as EE Captcha is being parsed and checked within add-on code...

Comment: have you looked at going directly to ReCaptcha? http://www.google.com/recaptcha/whyrecaptcha if you sign up there should be instructions on how to add to your site. Note I haven't signed up, just googled this.

Comment: Yes, I could use RECAPTCHA directly but I usually put any php into an add-on file instead of embedded in the page, if I used php. So then that would be an add-on anyway so I might as well use one already developed. I think it comes down to which captcha approach I decide to go with, a hidden field like Snaptcha or an image like reCAPTCHA.

Answer (score 1):

you could use [Snaptcha's](http://www.putyourlightson.net/snaptcha) {exp:snaptcha:field} template tag but you would need to run the field validation yourself. there are instructions on how to do this in the [docs](http://www.putyourlightson.net/snaptcha/docs#template_tags) but some php knowledge is required.

Comment: Ben, This looks like a good possibility. I looked at the documentation quickly but not sure yet how to do the validation. Would that be php embedded in the web page template? Or maybe, alternatively, a simple Exp Eng plugin file?

Comment: it depends on what the form does. i assume it collects some data and does something with it, most likely with php, and that's where want to add the validation. it will need to somehow be in an EE script or template to work in the high security level. if your php code is outside of EE then it should work but you'll need to use the medium or low level.

Comment: Ben, as an experiment I setup an Exp Eng custom module that simply creates the html of the form in a template using tags. My idea was that I could then incorporate Exp Eng's captcha system into the form. Then, hopefully, it wouldn't matter which type of captcha add-on I use. But I don't have enough experience with modules because, of course, just adding "captcha" in curly brackets the way you normally could doesn't work. I realize this is getting off topic but do you have any suggestions, like a function call or something, that would allow use of captchas in an add-on module?

Comment: see the developer documentation here (http://www.putyourlightson.net/snaptcha/docs#developers)

Comment: I've been experimenting with this after a long hiatus. I've installed the add-on and I'm able to include the snaptcha code in the form using 'exp:snaptcha:field security_level="3"'. The problem for me now is how to do the validation. The form simply does a POST on submit. How do I run a validation using Exp Eng add-on functions? I created a php function in my add-on that is separate from the one that creates the form itself. I tried just putting it in the page and got an error...

Comment: Here's the error...
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message:  Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER
Filename: snaptcha/ext.snaptcha.php
Line Number: 59

Comment: Sorry, the line number for the error is 599 not 59.